# Not parsing an hour from a joda DateTime

Tags: scala, jodatime

I'm trying to parse a string that contains a DateTime

```
  def parseDateTime(str : String) : DateTime = {
    //need to parse date time of this format
    //2015-05-22T05:10:00.305308666Z

    DateTime.parse(str,DateTimeFormat.forPattern(dateTimePattern))
  }

  def dateTimePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSSZ"
```

and here is my test case trying to parse the date time

```
 "MarshallerUtil" must "parse a date time correctly from blockcypher" in {
    val str = "2015-05-22T05:10:00.305308666Z"
    val dateTime = parseDateTime(str)
    dateTime.getYear must be (2015)
    dateTime.getMonthOfYear must be (DateTimeConstants.MAY)
    dateTime.getDayOfMonth must be (22)
    dateTime.getHourOfDay must be (5)
    dateTime.getMinuteOfHour must be (10)
  }
```

and it fails to get the correct hour

```
[info] - must parse a date time correctly from blockcypher *** FAILED ***
[info]   0 was not equal to 5 (MarshallerUtilTest.scala:17)
```

What is incorrect on my pattern?

Comment: First of all, you should put Z within apostrophes. "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS'Z'"

Comment: **Z** is used for timezone in the date time format, where as **T** is used as a separator between date and time. Though the above solves your issue, you should note that **Z** is for timezone and you should make sure you don't 'mis-parse' the date string.

Comment: @JavaAnto Sorry I deleted my comment because I think I ran into the exact issue you are talking about. Another test case failed saying that `"...5-05-22T05:10:00.305[-05:00]" was not equal to "...5-05-22T05:10:00.305[308666Z]""`

Comment: I don't think that the date string **2015-05-22T05:10:00.305308666Z** itself is correct. Because as I mentioned above **Z** should come only in the pattern and not in the date string. I would suggest that you remove the **Z** from both the string and the pattern.

Comment: On the api documentation I am looking at though they specifically give Z as part of the date time http://dev.blockcypher.com/#push-raw-transaction-endpoint look at the `received` field on the api example

Comment: and even if i remove the 'Z' from my pattern, I still receive this error `"...5-05-22T05:10:00.305[-05:00]" was not equal to "...5-05-22T05:10:00.305[308666]" (BlockCypherTransactionMarshallerTest.scala:80)`

Comment: That's because the two date strings in the error message differ in the following ways: 1. The timezone for the first is '-05:00' and for the second is '+00:00'. 2. The first date string has no micro seconds and the second one does. So it's obvious that the above comparison fails.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98600/discussion-between-java-anto-and-chris-stewart).

Comment: @ChrisStewart See my comment to Java Anto's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because it parses the date time as UTC and when you invoke the getHourOfDay, it returns the time unit with local timezone. For example the same program printed '10' here, because my local timezone is '+05:30' and so, 05:10 and a 05:30 is 10:40. I hope this helps.

**Update:**

**Z** is a placeholder/matcher that is used in the date time pattern to match a timezone. A timezone has the form '+HH:mm' or '-HH:mm', for example '+05:30' means that the timezone is 5 hours and 30 mins ahead of the UTC time.

Comment: Update 1 is wrong. `Z` in the datetime string _is_ a timezone: see https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt and http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/z (plus, `+05:30` is an offset, not a timezone: one timezone has different offsets over time, due to daylight savings and rule changes).